# Chsh Enterpise login

Tags: shell, fedora, zsh, passwd, domain

I installed Fedora 34 and did the Enterprise Login (domain user).

I can't use `chsh` for change the user default shell to zsh because user does not exists. (It's not present in `/etc/passwd` because is not a local user)

I tried to get the user string to add to `/etc/passwd` with `getent passwd $USER` but it doesn't work because in the string there is `@` symbol and it break the login.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly assign default shells to users when they are in Active Directory from a joined server. You could either change it on the server where they exist, using the respective commands or try to override it, but this will affect all users. If you are using SSSD for integration, you could edit /etc/sssd/sssd.conf on your Fedora machine and add

```
[domain/YOUR_DOMAIN]
override_shell = /bin/zsh
```

I advise you to always do the changes on the server where the domain is. This will save you a lot of problems in the future

Comment: You can change the default shell using the [loginShell attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-loginshell). That has to be done by a domain administrator though, not locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct the server to change the user's password. As far as I know, with LDAP/AD, the `chsh` command doesn't know how to do that, you have to call a [separately packaged](https://command-not-found.com/chsh.ldap) command [`chsh.ldap`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/chsh.ldap.1.html).

Note that this changes your shell on all machines using this network account, which means you won't be able to log in on a machine that doesn't have zsh installed (or has it in a different location).

Another method to choose a different login shell is to keep `/bin/sh` as your actual login shell (which exists everywhere), but instruct it to run a different program in `~/.profile`.

```
# ~/.profile
…
if [ -x /bin/zsh ]; then
  export SHELL=/bin/zsh
  exec $SHELL
fi
```